# Can i set which .so to link in php scripts?

Tags: php, shared-libraries

I have several copies of same ".so" file under different system directory. Can I set link path in my php scripts so that i can link to a certain ".so'?

Comment: What do you mean by linking to a .so file?

Comment: .so files are "shared objects", a lot like DLLs in Windows.  The OP seems to be asking if there's a way to specify which .so to load if you have multiple ones that could work (but have different names or at least locations, of course).

Answer (score 1):

See [`dl()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) and [Extension Loading Directives](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify which so you want to load in your /etc/php.ini file